# Ajax callout from latest salesforce1 version not working

Tags: javascript, rest-api, salesforce1-app, jquery, ajax

I am making an ajax callout to a google maps api(URL), from a VF page that is built for salesforce1 (iPad). 
The api I'm using is reverse geocoding.

When I debugged, the $j.Ajax function was not getting called.

**This is when I upgraded my salesforce1 version to the latest (7.3). Earlier it was working as expected.**

When I open the same page in /one/one.app it IS WORKING as expected.

Comment: Can I know the reason why this was down voted?

Answer (score 0):

you are absolutely correct in that the update is blocking AJAX requests for several scenarios. After speaking with support it sounds like this is scheduled to be resolved with the next Salesforce1 for iOS update, v7.3.1.